# Drawing on multicores machines

Tags: c#, multithreading, multicore, mschart

My application is using MS Charts, which shows very fast data
And when I open multiple windows my CPU is always < 25%.
I have 4 cores, so drawing in ms chart is performed only on 1 core.
How can I make it to use all cores

Comment: You cannot make a program use more cores than it was programmed to use. It sounds like MS Charts was programmed to use a single core, so that's as many as it will ever use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  Like any UI component, Chart can only perform drawing on a single thread.  Your program's main UI thread to be specific.  This is not normally a problem, the amount of pixels that a modern cpu core can whip to the screen greatly outpaces the human's eye ability to perceive them.  You do *not* want to keep it so busy that one core is burning 100% load for the main thread, that's going to be perceptible by the user when the UI thread starts responding sluggishly to mouse and keyboard input.  Fine-tuning this is certainly a programmer's job.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the drawing from multiple threads, otherwise only one thread is used.